# Trying to get default background color with GetObject();

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I'm trying to get the default Windows system background color in `COLORREF` format with this code:

```
 LOGBRUSH lb;
 GetObject((HANDLE)(COLOR_BACKGROUND), sizeof(LOGBRUSH), &lb);
 BG_COLOR = lb.lbColor;
 char buff[250];
 sprintf(buff, "BG_COLOR: 0x%08X;", BG_COLOR);
 MessageBoxA(0, buff, "Alert!", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
```

But it returns `0x003E28F4` which is **red** while setting a Window's class `hbrBackground` as `(HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND` like this:

```
WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
```

The background color for the window appears as **grey** (on WinXP) with hex `0x00C8D0D4` (checked with gimp).

As far as I know, `0x003E28F4` and `0x00C8D0D4` are not the same

What is causing this? How can I get the default background color in RGB/COLORREF format?

Comment: Have you tried `(HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND-1` ?

Comment: What does GetObject return?

Comment: you can't call `GetObject` with `COLOR_BACKGROUND`, it can only be used with `WndClass.hbrBackground` and therefore returns rubbish. Besides you need to add 1 to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `GetSysColor(COLOR_BACKGROUND)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx